# Flutter - RestAPI - Login

Tags: flutter, api, dart

Here I'm going to login using RestAPI.

And the API link they have given me is [link1](https://retoolapi.dev/B13laa/getusers?user_id=%3Cvalue1%3E&password=%3Cvalue2%3E) and they told me to use that to do login.

And also they told me that I can get the list of users with the help of this API [link2](https://retoolapi.dev/B13laa/getusers).

So how do I know that login is successful or not?

I tried below code and whatever I entered and press login it printing **Success**.

How do I do this in correct way?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  late final TextEditingController _email;
  late final TextEditingController _password;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // Email
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _email,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  label: Text('Email'),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Email is required';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ),
            // Password
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _password,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  label: Text('Password'),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Password is required';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ),
            // Login Button
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    try {
                      var response = await http.post(
                        // Uri.parse('https://retoolapi.dev/B13laa/getusers'),
                        Uri.parse(
                          'https://retoolapi.dev/B13laa/getusers?user_id=<value1>&password=<value2>',
                        ),
                        body: ({
                          'email': _email.text,
                          'password': _password.text,
                        }),
                      );

                      if (response.statusCode == 200 ||
                          response.statusCode == 400) {
                        print('Success');
                      } else {
                        print('Failed');
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      print(e.toString());
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Login'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter an invalid user_id and/or password, you get an empty response.
response.statusCode is 200 though.

You have to look at response.body to see the list of users. If it is empty, the login was not successful.

[image: From the dev tools]

Comment: I change my code in this way. ```var response = await http.post(
                        Uri.parse('https://retoolapi.dev/B13laa/getusers?${_email.text}user_id=&password=${_password.text}'),
                        body: ({
                          'email': _email.text,
                          'password': _password.text,
                        }),
                      );

                      print(response.body);```

Comment: Then it printing ***{
          "statusCode": 400,
          "error": "Bad Request",
          "message":
              "Number of rows exceeded 150. Contact support@retool.com to increase this limit."
        }*** Why is this happening?